# jquery- hide columns in table where there are rowspans

Tags: jquery, gridview, toggle

I need to hide columns in a table but there are rowspans involved and it messes up the function. I appreciate any help. Below is the link for my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/SEwVP/73/

Here is the function (in the example, I'm trying to hide the column 3):

```
$('#toggle').click(function(){
var lastChilds = $('#tbl td:nth-child(3)');
lastChilds.each(function(i){
    var rowSpan = $(this).attr('rowspan');
    if(rowSpan !== undefined){
      lastChilds.splice(i+1, rowSpan-1);

    }
     $(this).toggle();

  });
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

I was initially intrigued by this because it seems something trivial but in fact quite mind-boggling. I've tried various approaches to workaround the `rowspan`s to toggle the right cells. I initially answered yesterday but I deleted it soon enough because I know it failed miserably.

When we say '3rd column', it doesn't necessarily mean the `<td>` would be the third child of the row, because in terms of how HTML and `rowspan`s work.

Then comes the epiphany: tables are perfect grids, so for example, all cells that are **"visually perceived"** as the 3rd column all share one thing in common, **they all share the same offset left**.

This is the closest I could get so far, and this perhaps a somewhat radical approach that is **based on one important assumption: that no `colspan`s are involved in the entire table**. (Or else, everything turns into poop)

This demo allows you to toggle **any** column you want, hopefully with any rowspan complexity.

(If there is a more elegant solution I'd certainly want to know myself)

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/terryyounghk/nGEHW/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var $table = $('#tbl');

    (function scanTable($table) {

        var $rows = $table.find('tr'),
            $cells = $table.find('td'),
            map = {};

        // the first row will always have all n columns of cells,
        // so this is the safest row to collect each columns offset().left
        $rows.first().find('td').each(function (i, cell) {
            var $cell = $(cell),
                left = Math.floor($cell.offset().left);
            map[left] = i+1;
            $cell.attr({
                'data-nth-col': i+1
            });
        });

        // now for the rest of the rows, 
        $rows.not(':first').each(function (i, row) {
            var $row = $(row),
                $cells = $row.find('td');

            $cells.each(function (j, cell) {
                var $cell = $(cell),
                    left = Math.floor($cell.offset().left);
                $cell.attr({
                    'data-nth-col': map[left]
                });
            });
        });
    })($table); // scan the entire table ONCE. 
                // We don't want to do this on every toggle


    $('button[name=toggle]').on('click', function () {
        var n = +$(this).val();
        $table.find('td[data-nth-col='+n+']').toggle();
    });

});
```